# How do I enable a larger message size for specific controllers / actions only?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

I have a series of apis built using Web API 2.0. How can I increase the maximum message size for some actions and lower it for others? For example, I want a POST to /Person to have a maximum message size of 200 bytes but a bulk endpoint (POSTing to /Results) to be much larger.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an action filter that will prevent a message that is too large from being processed.  However, it will not prevent the server from actually receiving the message.

If you really want to prevent large messages from being received you will need to do that as a message handler and you would have to look at a portion of the URI to decide whether to fail or not.